# dns cache to run on a bastion host

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, firewall

I'm configuring a bastion host with Linux.  It will run DHCP and DNS (resolver, recursive and cache)

The solutions that I'm considering are:

- djbdns
- powerdns
- isc dns
- unbound

For DHCP I'm thinking about ISC DHCPD.

Something that I found interesting is [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).  What do you like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dnsmasq` is ideal for that role, although its configuration options are limited compared to a standalone DHCP or DNS server.  Many small home routers now use dnsmasq in their firmware.

Should you decide against that, I'd also suggest looking at [Unbound](http://www.unbound.net/) for the recursive resolver.  Because it's *only* a recursive resolver it's not bloated with the features that a general purpose server like BIND has, but it does also support DNSSEC out of the box, unlike djbdns.